# Выбор СУБД для реестра мониторинга и исполнения замечаний

Tags: база-данных, реестр, рассылка, мониторинг

Какую программу выбрать для реестра мониторинга и исполнения замечаний?

Реестр состоит: замечание, путь исправления (возможно несколько этапов), процент исполнения, ответственный за исполнение.
Необходима автоматическая рассылка, напоминание. Использование несколькими пользованиями одновременно. Выгрузка разных отчетов.
Сейчас в экселе, много файлов, запутались в них и учета нет.
Вероятно уже есть готовые платформы, например, как для сайтов.

Comment: То что вы хотите мне кажется называется "тикет система" в гугле по этим словам масса вариантов. Как точно это НЕ называется, так это СУБД, ибо СУБД это система для хранения данных, а вот программу для работы с этими данными вы пишите сами

Comment: Посмотрите Jira, наиболее распостранёная.

Comment: Вопросы вида "какую программу/систему выбрать" (из ограниченного круга вариантов) потенциально холиварные и не рекомендуются здесь (например, вышеприведенная система Jira лично меня бесит, хоть ей и все пользуются). Класс систем, среди которых вам нужно искать, называется "help desk". Гуглите по этому слову, смотрите что есть, выбирайте.